# A question about writing a wave as the superposition of other waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

In quantum mechanics, if a wave function is the superposition of many wave functions, it can be written as
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int g(k)e^{i(kx-\omega t)}dk \, .$$
On page 24 of *Quantum Mechanics* by Cohen-Tannoudji, Diu and Laloe, the following waves are superimposed: with wave numbers $\{ k_0, k_0 - \Delta k/2, k_0 + \Delta k / 2 \}$. However the expression that they write for it is
$$
  \frac{g(k)}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left(
      e^{ik_0x}
    + e^{i \left(k_0+\frac{\Delta k}{2} \right) x}
    + e^{i \left(k_0-\frac{\Delta k}{2} \right) x} 
  \right) \, .
$$
Shouldn't it be
$$
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left(
      g(k_0)e^{ik_0x}
    + g(k_0 + \Delta k / 2) e^{i \left(k_0+\frac{\Delta k}{2} \right) x}
    + g(k_0 - \Delta k / 2) e^{i \left(k_0-\frac{\Delta k}{2} \right) x}
  \right)
  \, ?
$$

Comment: Should those $\Delta x/2$ be $\Delta k/2$?

Comment: From the book: "... [the] amplitudes [of these plane waves] are proportional, respectively, to 1, 1/2 and 1/2." Thus, there is an overall factor of $g(k_0)$ out front (roughly speaking a normalization factor), and then the corresponding factors of 1, 1/2, and 1/2 are attached to each plane wave. For instance, what you called $g(k_0 + \Delta k/2)$ is equal to $g(k_0)/2$.